# Opening and closing outlook .msg files with vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hello guys i have the following code which gives me an automation error after the first file is opened and closed.
Run-time error '-2147023170 (800706be) automation error the remote procedure call failed. Please help im getting so close to getting excel to open and read and then close all my outlook .msg files

```
Sub Kenneth_Li()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
inPath = "C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+"

thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
Do While thisFile <> ""

    'Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(thisFile)
    'Or
    'Set Msg = objOL.OpenSharedItem(thisFile)
    Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(inPath & "\" & thisFile)

    Msg.Display

    Msg.Close olSave
    'MsgBox Msg.Subject
    thisFile = Dir
Loop


Set objOL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone there i really need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me.

I suggest you try late binding as below.

Googling your error did also throw up the RPC Service as a potential issue.

```
Sub Kenneth_Li()
Dim objOL As Object
Dim Msg As Object

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
inPath = "C:\temp"

thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
Do While thisFile <> ""

    Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(inPath & "\" & thisFile)
    Msg.Display
    Msg.Close olSave
    thisFile = Dir
Loop


Set objOL = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: late binding? yea i just tried out your code, still it opens and closes the first .msg file, then proceeds on to give me an automation error. is there anything else that im missing permissions etc? @brettdj thanks for replying. Sometimes it gives the automation error, sometimes it gives a run-time error 462, the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable.

Comment: in addition i found this online- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178510 but im not sure what my next step should be.

Answer (score 0):

RPC_S_CALL_FAILED usually mean the out-of-proc COM server (Outlook) terminated while you still had a reference to one of its objects.

If Outlook running at the time your code is executed the error is returned?

Comment: yes outlook was running why dont you try the code below, i still dont know what to do.